# Prove that a Linear Transformation is Normal, such that $T^2=T$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> Let V be a finite  inner product space and $T:V\rightarrow V$ a linear transformation such that $$T^2=\frac{1}{2}(T+T^*)$$.
>
> Prove that
>
> 1. $T$ is a "Normal Transformation", such that $$TT^*=T^*T$$
> 2. $T^2=T$

Proving the first statement isn't hard and I did it that way:

$T^*=2T^2-T$ $\Rightarrow TT^*=T(2T^2-T)=(2T^2-T)T=T^*T$

Therefore,  $TT^*=T^*T$.

However, proving the second statement was much harder, and I couldn't figure it out.

Thanks,

Alan

Comment: Is $V$ finite dimensional?

Comment: Yes. I will edit my post, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Once you know that $T$ is normal, then it has a basis of eigenvectors. An eigenvalue $\lambda$ must satisfy
$$
              \lambda^{2}=\frac{1}{2}(\lambda+\overline{\lambda})=\Re\lambda.
$$
The only way $\lambda^{2}$ is real is if $\lambda$ is real or is purely imaginary. However, $\lambda=ir$ for some real $r$ gives $-r^{2}=\Re(ir)=0$. So $\lambda$ must be real. Furthermore $\lambda^{2}=\Re\lambda=\lambda$, which means that $T^{2}=T$ also holds.